# Find the sum of the value $\left|\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}w^{j^2}\right|$

Tags: number-theory, summation

> Let $p$ be prime number,and $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, and $w=e^{\frac{2\pi}{p}\cdot i}$. Find the value
>   $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}w^{j^2}\right|$$

it seem use Quadratic Residues?

Comment: Since the [quadratic Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) $g(1;p)=i\sqrt{p}$, the sum is $(i\sqrt{p}-1)/2$ with absolute value $\sqrt{p+1}/2$.

Answer (score 4):

First you can observe that $$\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} w^{j^2} = \sum_{j=\frac{p-1}{2}+1}^{p-1} w^{(p-j)^2} = \sum_{j=\frac{p-1}{2}+1}^{p-1} w^{j^2}$$

So $$\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} w^{j^2} = \frac12 \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} w^{j^2} = \frac12 \left(\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} w^{j^2} - 1\right) = \frac12 (g(1;p) - 1) = \frac12 (-1 +i\sqrt p)$$

Comment: How to prove this $g(1;p)=i\sqrt{p}?$

Comment: Look at this article http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/quadratic2.pdf

Comment: @inequality did the article show you what do you want ?